# Does this "to" mean "will"?

Tags: grammar

In this sentence:

> I want you *to* do it.

Does "to" here mean "will"?

Comment: **To** is just an infinitive marker, a pair of letters used with the base form of a verb to indicate that the verb is in the infinitive: *to do.* Are you confusing it with **want**? To *will* for something is to *want* the thing to happen.

Answer (score 1):

**SHORT ANSWER:**
No. It is what is often called an *infinitive marker*, meaning that it marks the ‘plain’ form of the verb which follows as an infinitive.

**LONGER ANSWER:**
In Old English, the ‘infinitive’ form of the verb could be recognized by a distinctive ending, which itself could take additional endings designating case, since the infinitive acted as a noun. One very common construction, the ‘dative infinitive’ used the preposition *to* with an infinitive in the dative case to express purpose; it survives to this day.

> ... Þæt mod ... ÞencÞ fela godra werka **to wyrcanne** ...
>   ... the mind ... conceives many good works **to do**

During the Middle English phase of the language, however, these endings were lost. In consequence, there was no longer any way of distinguishing the infinitive from the ordinary present-tense form of the verb. Because it was already in widespread use in the dative infinitive construction, the preposition *to* was recruited to remedy this lack.

Except as the complement of modal verbs (*can/could, may/might, shall/should, will/would*), the infinitive today is almost always marked with *to*, which in this context has no prepositional sense whatever.